# Strange Response Interpretation From Server using React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using "React Native" in order to create an application for that acts as a web server that currently exist (can't disclose for privacy reasons). I am trying to create a Login Page, everything is set up to start a request using the in build "fetch(url)" command.

```
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  constructor (Props) {
    super(Props);
    this.state={
    username:'',
    password:'',
    Response:''
  }
  // bindings to state
  this.Login = this.Login.bind(this); // you need this to be able to access state from login
  this.HttpRequest = this.HttpRequest.bind(this);
  this.ValidateResponse = this.ValidateResponse.bind(this);
}

Login(){
  requestURL = sURL + "usr=" + this.state.username + "&" + "pwd=" + this.state.password;

  var response = this.HttpRequest(requestURL);
  this.setState({Response: "Response: " + JSON.stringify(response)});
}

HttpRequest(url){
  return fetch(url)
  .catch((error) => {
  this.setState({Response: "Error: " + error});
  });
}

ValidateResponse(response){
  this.setState({Response: "Validating Login...\n" + response});
}

render() {
  return (
    // The Container for the Activity
    <View style={styles.container}>

      {/* The Image of The MiBase Logo */}
      <View style={styles.MiBaseLogo}>
        <Image resizeMode="contain" style={styles.MiBaseLogoImage} source={require("./mibaselogo.png")}/>
      </View>

      {/* The Text Input for the username and password*/}
      <TextInput style={styles.Username} placeholder="Username" placeholderTextColor="rgb(200,200,200)"
        onChangeText={(username) => {this.setState({username})}}/>
      <TextInput style={styles.Password} placeholder="Password" placeholderTextColor="rgb(200,200,200)"
        onChangeText={(password) => {this.setState({password})}} secureTextEntry={true}/>

      {/* The Button to Command the Login Functionality */}
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.LoginButton} onPress={this.Login}>
        <Text style={styles.LoginButtonText}>Login</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* The Text To Output Success or Report Failure */}
      <View style={styles.TextOutput}>
        <Text style={styles.TextOutputText}>{this.state.Response}</Text>
      </View>

    </View>
  );
}
```

}

This is the code for my Page/Activity. I am new at this so i'm not sure if this is typically how it is done, but in order to send a request a global variable "sURL" (Assigned the name of the server) has the varaibles (usr & pwd) appended to it and sent off using fetch. when i json.stringify the response and return it to my debugging test the response is thus
[Image of Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m07rj.png)

The response when using a Http Get Request (through chrome) is 
{"member": {"username":"","password":"","key":"b54d42c276a76283013589a7c285eebf","status":"No"}}

Can anyone explain this or work out what i did wrong?

Comment: The Response the server returns is in the form of a string containing the values of a JSON object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are getting that error, I just made a form yesterday using https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native and it was very easy and worked straight away.

I get the impression though that your problem lies with your fetch, do you have access to the api backend? Also are you sending passwords in the url???

What kind of response are you expecting? When creating a login page you should really only need to know if the server accepted the login or not

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of my login fetch posting the login details to my API as a POST request:

```
onLoginPress = () => {
        const value = this._form.getValue(); 

            if(value != null){
                 this.setState({
                    fetching: true
                 })

                var AdminLoginBindingModel = {
                    AdminID: 0,
                    AdminName: value.Username,
                    AdminPassword: value.Password,
                    }

                fetch(YOUR API END POINT',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },     
                    body: JSON.stringify(AdminLoginBindingModel)
                    })       
                    .then((res) => res.json())
                    .then((json) => {
                        console.log(json);
                        this.setState({
                            isLoggedIn: true
                        })

                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        this.setState({
                            error: 'Something went wrong!' + error,
                            isLoggedIn: false,
                            fetching: false
                        })
                    })
            }                         
      }
```

Thats how I would do it but you are sending you login details as a part of the url and from your code it looks fine.

**EDIT 2:**

```
constructor(props){super(props);
this.state = {
API_Response_Status: false,
JSON_Response: {}
  }
}
```

Then:

```
fetch(YOUR API END POINT',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },     
                body: JSON.stringify(AdminLoginBindingModel)
                })       
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((json) => {
                    console.log(json);

                    this.setState({
                        API_Response_Status: true,
                        JSON_Response: json
                    })
                    console.log(this.state.JSON_Response);
                    console.log(this.state.API_Response_Status);

                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        error: 'Something went wrong!' + error,
                        API_Response_Status: false,
                        fetching: false
                    })
                })
        }
```

Comment: To answer your questions, i do have access to the api back end, the password is sent directly in the url the current system has no sensitive data associated with the accounts this is for convenience only, i'm expecting a response of a JSON Object (can be found in the question). The Response will always be a JSON object if it comes from the server with the "status" returning yes or no respectively. The reason for the somewhat strange system is because it is being adapted from an already existing web server

Comment: Ok, im no expert but from my troubles with my login page i can tell you my issues were that I needed to specify that it was a post request, supply headers in the request so the server know what its getting, i had to change the api method to accept from body. Dont know if that helps you but it might point you to a few changes you could try

Comment: It does help a little, what i'm really trying to do is send a http "GET" request using the url as the form and return that to check if its valid. Is that not how fetch works?

Comment: I just updated my answer but you are sending as a query string instead, even so i would include headers in your request anyway

Comment: i made a mistake in my question. the server doesn't respond with a JSON object it responds with a string of a JSON object. How would i change this method you have create to accept a string?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the response, if you just want to check the status then have you can have a local state variable and set that in the response. I'll update the answer again to reflect this

Comment: This is off the top of my head so dont might not be great syntax but you get the idea, in the reposnse you can check the reponse and set your state, then you can open the next page if the status is true and not if false

Comment: I get and error, which is the same as when i don't parse json and just try to print response, TypeError: undefined is not a object (evaluating 'input.bodyUsed')

Comment: I would guess that your url is wrong, can you debug the api? See what it thinks its getting? I never send stuff via query string so am not sure but that would be my guess

Comment: Are you expecting a list? what do you mean by string of JSON objects

Comment: I may have phrased it wrong, The server sends back a string. This is a stringied JSON object. like this '{"member": {"username":"","password":"","key":"b54d42c276a76283013589a7c285eebf","status":"No"}}'

Comment: yeah so its a json object. im afraid i dont think i can help you, If you used my example then your API would be expecting a POST request (which you say it isnt) so that would return nothing, you dont stringify a query string so trying to send that could return nothing also. Im afaid without seeing your api code this is beyond me. I hope you find help, good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help, i think i just have a very basic understanding of react native so its hard to wrap my head around all this

Comment: No problem i only started with it 2 weeks ago so i feel your pain! If you are certain that your API is expecting a GET then you dont need to send a json body so my example wont work. If you have access to the API i would just change that method to a POST, and serialize the username and password and send that. Good luck

Comment: I fiddled around with your method a little more, i found the main issue is the use of forms. i changed the data to be stored in state variables and everything worked fine, i now receive a response from the server

Comment: Thats great :) Happy you got it sorted